# Disable mouse interations

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm designing a Qml application that is meant to be interacted with only by keyboard and I would like to disable mouse interactions

how would you do that ?

Comment: The biggest question is: why would you ever do that? Note that there's mouse interaction, and then there's touch interaction. Frankly said, if I were your user and were subjected to such treatment, I'd probably have an ill wish or two for you :( Furthermore, on devices with no keyboard attached (say: a tablet running "desktop" Windows 8/10), you're essentially forcing your user to use on-screen keyboard. Is your application properly dealing with resizing itself when the on-screen keyboard is present? I'm worried that you haven't given it much though from the usability angle at all.

Comment: @KubaOber no worries, there is use cases where it needs to be like that. the application is to be used internally and we are used to it. also implementing both keyboard and mouse interactivity creates more issues and it's a lot of work, so for now, I looking to just disable the mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either:

1. Use an event filter in C++ that steals all mouse events, or
2. Place a `MouseArea` above all other items in the scene (for example, as the last item declared in your `main.qml`) that does nothing when it receives events.

Or... just don't use items that have mouse interaction. :)